# How do I use the Combine XYZ node with a quadratic curve bezier node?

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, vector

I'm trying to randomize the control points of a quadratic bezier node.  However, when I try to combine xyz with the random value node, I get this mysterious red dashed line:
[image]

How can I randomize the values in the quadratic bezier node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach an *Integer* node to the *ID* input of the Random Value Node (Must be an integer - not a float or vector):

[image: INt]

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I'm doing it again because I think it's important to "spread the word" so to speak, that a new feature of the updated geometry nodes is that in some cases (such as this one), the *Inputs* you feed to certain nodes are able to change the *Output Type*.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!  I spent about an hour searching for an answer, but my efforts were fruitless.  Much appreciated!!